# Compare two rows in R and delete the rows when the boolean expression changes from 1 to 0

Tags: r

I have the following data set in R

```
data1  data2  data3  Flag
A      A1     B2     0
A      A1     B2     1
B      C1     C2     1
```

I would like to compare the rows and delete the rows with Flag=1 when the flag values changes from 1 to 0 if rest of the values for that particular row are equal to the other row to which is being compared on.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. But this is what I did:

```
data1 <- c("A","A","B")
data2 <- c("A1","A1","C1")
data3 <- c("B2","B2","C2")
Flag <- c(0,1,1)
df <- data.frame(data1, data2, data3, Flag)
```

Using dplyr, I removed all the rows where Flag = 1 and saved the output in another data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>%
  filter(Flag != 1)
```